# How to select multiple entries in address book using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, abpeoplepickerview

I need to allow the user to select multiple entries from the iPhone address book before proceeding to the next action.

Currently if I use the ABPeopleNavigationController, it only allows me to pick one entry at a time. Is there any way to allow multiple selections i.e. add a checkmark beside all the names I want to select before clicking on 'done' button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible with the standard `ABPeopleNavigationController`.

You'll have to use a `UITableView` to provide the list of people to select and enable multiple selection - basically you have to do it all yourself. It isn't that hard. Just write a custom table data source on your list of people.